# App crash when calling MessageBox

Tags: c#, .net, messagebox

Hello i call up a MessageBox when validating some data, if the data is wrong I message the user with a MessageBox with following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox_name.Text.Trim() != "" 
        || textBox_X.Text.Trim() != "" 
        || textBox_Y.Text.Trim() != "")
    {
        if (graph.getNodoNome(textBox_nome.Text.Trim()) != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Data is wrong?", "Error");

            resetTextBoxes();
            return;
        }

    // randome stuff
    }
}
```

My app crash with this, when i remove the MessageBox works fine. Thanks for the help

EDIT: Pastebay link for the entire method http://pastebay.com/82690

Comment: What is the error message / exception you get when the program crashes?

Comment: Made a try catch on the MessageBox, doesnt say anything. Simply crash.

Comment: What about formatting your code correctly? *How* does the app crash (which exception is thrown)?

Comment: We won't be able to help you with such a general description of a problem. What exception is thrown when the application crashes? Without knowing that we can only give very general advice: Do you have all the necessary references? Have you tried rebuilding your project after changing dependencies?

Comment: @AndiDog I am trying to learn to format correctly! As far as i can see it, no exception is thrown

Comment: @Rekreativc is there any necessary reference for the MessageBox?

Comment: Doesn't look like the MessageBox is your problem - maybe a nasty multithreading problem?! Try `Debug.WriteLine("BAM"); Thread.Sleep(5000);` before and after the MessageBox call -> what is shown in the output?

Comment: System.Windows.Forms I believe is needed.

Comment: I really doubt the MessageBox is really the problem here. Put a try catch statement around the whole function (and dont forget to catch a exception like this: try {stuff ... } catch (Exception ex) { handle the error.} Paste the ex.Message here so we can help you!

Comment: AndiDog, there is nothing in there to indicate any threading problem. From the question there are no threads mentioned.... How on earth are you making that assumption?

Comment: @Ian: I don't assume it, it's just a possibility. And from my experience with C++, the most weird bugs (like this one) always appeared when I used threads ;)

Comment: @Rekreativc I do that, and no exception is thrown. @AndiDog i dont know how to do multi-threading, i've not tried it. And i cant use those classes you gave me, i dont know what references to use.

Comment: @Ricardo: `Thread.Sleep` should be available with `using System.Threading`.

Comment: AndiDog: This is C# question, and since it is taged beginner I really don't think threads are relavant. Ricardo: How exactly does it crash then? Can you describe the crash in greater detail? Just in case I am wrong and threads are important here, for AndiDog's advice you will need to include System.Diagnostics and System.Threading .

Comment: Even though threads might not be relevant, my `Debug.WriteLine` approach *could* tell him when the crash happens. The sleeping is just for flushing stdout/stderr (don't know if that matters in C#)...

Comment: Are you sure it is the messagebox call that crashes? Have you tried to single step in debug?

Comment: Sorry for my delay. @AndiDog I get the "BAM"! And the application still crashes. @Rekreativc I've made a break point in the MessageBox call, and far as i can tell there are no null variables, everything is as it should be.

Comment: I think maybe it's time to find somewhere you can upload you're code to allow someone to download it and try it...

Comment: @lan thanks for the heads up. Here is the link http://pastebay.com/82690

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mention the type of exception.

Since I can't assume that, I'll comment on other potential sources of error?

Honestly also, your

```
        if (textBox_nome.Text.Trim() != "" 
            || textBox_X.Text.Trim() != "" 
            || textBox_Y.Text.Trim() != "")
```

should be

```
        if (textBox_nome.Text.Trim() != "" 
            && textBox_X.Text.Trim() != "" 
            && textBox_Y.Text.Trim() != "")
```

to make sure all fields are filled in.

Int.Parse will throw if invalid, I suggest (in pseudo C#):

```
int x;
if(!int.TryParse(text, out x)) x = 0; // some default value
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Right now I'm a bit low on time, but I'll check this as soon as i can. I think it might be it

Answer (score 0):

I think we need more info on the "graph.getNodoNome" and "randome stuff" parts.  If you comment out those lines, it runs just fine.  I pretty much guarantee the message box is not the problem.

I would bet it’s the getNodoNome method or the random stuff that is getting you.

1) Comment them both out, and see if it "crashes."
2) Uncomment the first "graph.getNodoNome" and see if it crashes
3) Comment out "graph..." uncomment "randome stuff" and see if it crashes

If you're not getting error messages, you need to take baby steps.

Comment: graph.getNodoNome(string N) finds and returns an Object, if not found it returns null. If i comment the "MessageBox.Show("Data is wrong?", "Error");" and i make the IF condition true, there are no errors and the resetTextBoxes() works fine.

Comment: Is graph from a third party library, or is it code you wrote? If a third party library, which one?

Comment: Try this, instead of using "return."  Just have an "else" statement after the "if (graph.getNodoNome(textBox_nome.Text.Trim()) != null)."  Put the "random stuff" in that else statement.  I wonder if the immediate return is doing something strange with the message box.

Also, I'd like to see the code for:
GetNodoNome code.